# English equivalent of "Always looking out the window"

Tags: idioms, phrase-requests, translation

In spanish there is **ventanear** and its derived terms, meaning to look out the window, in a busybody/nosey way. (It could also mean to peep into windows, in some places, but that's not important). It is literally derived from *ventana* (window).

Is there an English equivalent word or phrase? It brings to mind Gladys Kravitz from the show Bewitched. I know busybody is partly close, but it doesn't require peeking or watching from afar.

Comment: Idiomatically, perhaps [***nosey parker***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nosey%20parker) might do you (but it is primarily BrE).

Comment: Perhaps a **stealth ogler**.

Comment: Another word for *nosey parker* is *busybody*, a "meddling or prying person" (google).  But it doesn't specify the curtains or the window.  By the way, *nosy* (adj.) is also possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spanish word draws on a part of a house and listening in by association. The *eaves* are a part of the house in English and an *eavesdropper* listens in conversations because they are nosey.

Associating the nosey neighbor with an external part of the house is universal. Consider the Chinese word for [eavesdropping](http://en.bab.la/dictionary/english-chinese/eavesdropping) and a native speaker would see an ear next to a gate.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/165405/48273 hmm how easily you forget the root of common words :D Thank you.

Comment: I don’t understand your point about Chinese 偷听 _tōutīng_, which literally means ‘steal-hear’ or more accurately ‘hear surreptitiously’. There is nothing about any part of a house in that expression, and neither ears nor gates figure in either of the characters in the word. How is the Chinese word relevant here?

Answer (score 2):

My mother used to say that nosy neighbors who peeked out of their windows from behind their curtains were *"curtain peepers"*.  She said the phrase in a disapproving way, implying that such people were sneaky and felt they were "too good" to be openly curious.

Mother might have coined the term or she may have heard it as a child.  She was raised by Croatian and Swedish parents in a multi-language immigrant community in Michigan, U.S.A.  I haven't heard anyone outside our family say *curtain peeper* but, then again, I grew up far from her home town.

Comment: A quick search shows nothing for that. Google translate doesn't show a direct croatian ir swedish translation for "peeper", so it may just be lost in translation or http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BluntMetaphorsTrauma

Comment: I can't exactly recall the phrase I heard in my childhood (New England), but it involved curtains.  Peering or peeking through curtains, or twitching the curtain aside -- something like that.   A nosy neighbor who had peeked through the curtains often offers a vital clue in detective stories.

Answer (score 1):

In British English, "curtain twitcher".

https://forums.moneysavingexpert.com/showthread.php?t=3498537